# Underline is not disappearing from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, diff

I am using jsdiff from ejohn [here](http://ejohn.org/files/jsdiff.js)

But i am getting underline under text. This underline is coming from user agent style sheet.

Here is link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mw3uF/46/). You can see that i am getting underline. I tried using `text-decoration:none` but doesnt help.

To call jsDiff just use below code

```
document.body.innerHTML = diffString(
"How are you.",
"How are you all");
```

Comment: But `text-decoration:none` is the only answer to this.

Comment: `text-decoration: none;` works: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/mw3uF/56/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `text-decoration: none` on your `ins` element, like so:

```css
ins{
    background:#E6FFE6;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/mw3uF/57/).

Comment: Many thanks it worked. Do you know why we are unable to modify jsfiddle and update it with new link?